# Generic Hibernate Dao with Interface model object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I meet some problems with genericDao and model Interface.

I implemented the following GenericHibernateDao :

```
@Repository
public abstract class GenericHibernateDao<T, PK extends Serializable> implements IGenericDao<T, PK> {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Class<T> type;

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public GenericHibernateDao() {
    Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
    type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Transactional
public T add(T obj){
    getSession().persist(obj);
    return obj;
}

@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getById(PK id){
    T result = (T) getSession().load(type, id);
    return result;
}

@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> list(){
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(type);
    return (List<T>) crit.list();
}
...
```

This works perfectly fine for "normal" objects.

I'm trying to use Interface as type T (ex: IBattery):

```
public class BatteryDao extends GenericHibernateDao<IBattery, Integer> implements IBatteryDao {

}
```

-

```
public interface IBattery {

  public int getId();

  public double getLevel();
  public void setLevel(double _level);
}
```

-

```
@Entity
public class SimulationBattery implements IBattery {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(unique = false, nullable = false)
private double level;

@Override
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public double getLevel() {
    return level;
}

@Override
public void setLevel(double _level) {
    level = _level;
}
```

I instanciate IBattery through Spring applicationContext file to load a SimulationBattery implementation.
It works for persist, list (with criteria) but fail with "getById" cause of load, sending :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: ***.***.****.IBattery
```

That's right cause only implementation (SimulationBattery) are mapped in hibernate.cfg.xml, but I don't understand why I can add, list, but not load...
Someone has explanation ?

Thank you.

Fabien.

(I'm using Hibernate, Spring and Java8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you persist an entity, you pass a concrete entity instance to Hibernate. So Hibernate receives an instance of SimulationBattery, for example, and thus knows the type of the entity you're persisting: SimulationBattery.

When you list, you rely on the polymorphic feature of Hibernate: you ask Hibernate to return all the entity instances of IBattery. Hibernate knows all the concrete entity classes that implement this interface (SimulationBattery and ProductionBattery, for example). So it loads them all from the database, and returns them.

But when you ask for one specific entity by ID, all Hibernate knows is that the entity is one of the entities that implement IBattery, and that its ID is the one you pass (42 for example). That is not sufficient. You might want the SimulationBattery 42, or the ProductionBattery 42, and Hibernate doesn't know. Hence the failure.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So, finally, I have to overwrite SpringMVC injection and manually do it. It is so frustrating ...